# SSL certificate getting F Grade CVE-2016-2107

Tags: ssl

I am facing weird scenario. Consider the scenario very carefully plz to help solving problem.

I have 3 SSL on 3 domains `x,y` and `z`, on two different servers (both un-managed and windows servers) **a** and **b**.

`x` is hosted at server **a** while `y` and `z` are hosted at server **b** (with two virtual IPs).

y is (Dot-Net website so) deployed to `IIS` at port `443` while Both x and z are (nodejs/express sites so) running on `node` server at port `98`.

Using [Qualys SSL test](http://ssllabs.com/ssltest/) Both x and y are getting **A** grade but z is getting **F**.

[image]

The result tells there is no protocol support. I read the docs but got no guide to improve protocol support.
What I have tried is I had updated latest ssl 1.02h 3-may-2016. Still no luck.

I am stuck for two reasons.

1. Why at same server I am getting A grade for other domain?
2. Why on other server I am getting A with same scenario => When port, certificate installation process etc, everything is same?

Comment: Give us the three domains so we can take a look.

Comment: restart the http server?  better yet is the web framework using the ssl you upgraded?

Comment: What do you mean by port `98`? Do you have nginx or something else that proxies port 443 to 98? Site z is obviously running on port 443.

Comment: @xguru Yes. Server had been restarted after ssl upgrade.

Comment: @RustyX yes/ both x and y are running on port 98. I am actaully developer, network admin (who is not available for the time being) did the the port mapping things.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/openssl-may-2016/

Comment: Upgrade nodejs.

Comment: So you mean i should update nodejs. I am giving this a try but not sure it would solve cause, on server a It is installed the earlier version and still that is giving A grade. But i am going to try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was having same issue. Node needed to upgrade in order to be protected against the disclosed vulnerabilities. Its written in node.js [openssl updates for node.js](http://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/openssl-may-2016). xguru amd RuskyX gives 100% right answer.